# Grouping records based on continuous dates

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am a Spark SQL query developer. I have a complex requirement to group records based on contiguous/continuous dates.

First we need to order the records in `ASC` order based on `strt_dt` and `dschrg_dt` for the same patient (X5624). Once the ordering is done -

**Step1**:
we need to check if these records are contiguous/continuous - i.e if they have continuous dates. In other words, whether the `dschrg_dt` of the previous record is equal to the `strt_dt` of the current record. If yes, then all such records should be grouped under the same group.
**Step 2**:
If there is any **gap** of 1 or more days between the `dschrg_dt` of the previous record and the `strt_dt` of the current record, that group ends and then a **new** group should start, and all contiguous records that comes after that will belong to that new group until another gap occurs.
**Step3**:
For each such groups (identified in Step 1 above), find the main record (within that group) that has the maximum span (in days) between `strt_dt` and `dschrg_dt`, and then copy its `group-id` to all the remaining records in that very group.

Input:

```
GroupId | pat_id | clm_num  | clm_line |  strt_dt    | dschrg_dt
123-1   |  X5624 | 123      |   1      | 05-Jan-2019 | 07-Jan-2019 
629-3   |  X5624 | 629      |   3      | 07-Jan-2019 | 14-Jan-2019
918-2   |  X5624 | 918      |   2      | 14-Jan-2019 | 15-Jan-2019
307-1   |  X5624 | 307      |   1      | 08-May-2019 | 11-May-2019
478-3   |  X5624 | 478      |   3      | 11-May-2019 | 12-Jan 2019
```

Expected Output:

```
Group Id | pat_id | clm_num | clm_line |  strt_dt    | dschrg_dt   | main_rec_ind
629-3    |  X5624 | 123     |   1      | 05-Jan-2019 | 07-Jan-2019 | N
629-3    |  X5624 | 629     |   3      | 07-Jan-2019 | 14-Jan-2019 | Y
629-3    |  X5624 | 918     |   2      | 14-Jan-2019 | 15-Jan-2019 | N
307-1    |  X5624 | 307     |   1      | 08-May-2019 | 11-May-2019 | Y
307-1    |  X5624 | 478     |   3      | 11-May-2019 | 12-Jan 2019 | N
```

Please note the following:

- All the records belong to patient X5624 and the entire record set is
  sorted on `strt_dt` & `dschrg_dt`
- First 3 records in the input are continuous i.e the previous record's
  `dschrg_dt` is equal to current record's `strt_dt`. Hence, these 3
  records fall in same group.
- The main record in this group is the `2nd` record since its span of
  days between `strt_dt` and `dschrg_dt` is `14` days which is greater than all other records in that same group. Hence it's Group Id '629-3' gets copied to the other
  records in it's group. Similarly the main record of the second group is the 4th record
- Now the 4th record has a gap between its previous record (3rd record) and hence is not continuous with the 3rd record and so will fall in a new group
- However, the 5th record is continuous to the 4th record and hence will also fall in the second group and get its `GroupId` from the 4th record (`307-1`)

Could anyone please help me implement this in Spark SQL query ? So far, I have only been able to identify contiguous records, but couldn't get the `GroupId` of the main record to copy to other records in that group.

```
select
groupid, pat_id, clm_num, clm_line, strt_dt, dschrg_dt,
case 
   when lag(dschrg_dt is null
   then 'true'
   when lag(dschrg_dt) over (partition by pat_id order by strt_dt asc, dschrg_dt desc) = strt_dt
   then 'true'
   else 'false'
end as tmp_grp
from pat_clms;
```

I am unable to proceed from here. Could anyone please help me implement this in Spark SQL query ?Any input is appreciated. Happy to provide more information if required. Many Thanks.

Comment: Add you create data statements pls.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning `true` and `false` to `tmp_grp` you may assign a `0` when contiguous and `1` otherwise. Creating a cumulative sum on this new column will assign different group numbers. With your newly realized groups you can then determine the record within each group with the maximum span (using `datediff` and a case expression or `when`) and subsequently replicate this group id for all rows within the group using `max` as a window function.

Eg

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(dschrg_dt,strt_dt) = MAX(DATEDIFF(dschrg_dt,strt_dt)) OVER (
                 PARTITION BY pat_id,gn
             ) THEN GroupId
    END as main_rec_ind
FROM (
    SELECT 
       *,
       SUM(contiguous) OVER (
           PARTITION BY pat_id
           ORDER BY strt_dt asc, dschrg_dt desc
        ) as gn
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            CASE
                WHEN LAG(dschrg_dt,1,strt_dt) OVER (
                         PARTITION BY pat_id
                         ORDER BY strt_dt asc, dschrg_dt desc
                     ) = strt_dt THEN 0
               ELSE 1
            END contiguous
        FROM
            pat_clms
    ) t1
) t2
```

Outputs:

```
+-------+------+-------+--------+----------+----------+----------+---+------------+
|GroupId|pat_id|clm_num|clm_line|strt_dt   |dschrg_dt |contiguous|gn |main_rec_ind|
+-------+------+-------+--------+----------+----------+----------+---+------------+
|123-1  |X5624 |123    |1       |2019-01-05|2019-01-07|0         |0  |null        |
|629-3  |X5624 |629    |3       |2019-01-07|2019-01-14|0         |0  |629-3       |
|918-2  |X5624 |918    |2       |2019-01-14|2019-01-15|0         |0  |null        |
|307-1  |X5624 |307    |1       |2019-05-08|2019-05-11|1         |1  |307-1       |
|478-3  |X5624 |478    |3       |2019-05-11|2019-01-12|0         |1  |null        |
+-------+------+-------+--------+----------+----------+----------+---+------------+
```

Your desired query may look like

```sql
SELECT
    GroupId, 
    pat_id, 
    clm_num, 
    clm_line, 
    strt_dt, 
    dschrg_dt,
    MAX(main_rec_ind) OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id,gn) main_rec_ind
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(dschrg_dt,strt_dt) = MAX(DATEDIFF(dschrg_dt,strt_dt)) OVER (
                     PARTITION BY pat_id,gn
                 ) THEN GroupId
        END as main_rec_ind
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *,
            SUM(contiguous) OVER (
                PARTITION BY pat_id
                ORDER BY strt_dt asc, dschrg_dt desc
            ) as gn
        FROM (
            SELECT
                *,
                CASE
                    WHEN LAG(dschrg_dt,1,strt_dt) OVER (
                             PARTITION BY pat_id
                             ORDER BY strt_dt asc, dschrg_dt desc
                         ) = strt_dt THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
                END contiguous
            FROM
                pat_clms
        ) t1
    ) t2
) t3
```

Outputs:

```
+-------+------+-------+--------+----------+----------+------------+
|GroupId|pat_id|clm_num|clm_line|   strt_dt| dschrg_dt|main_rec_ind|
+-------+------+-------+--------+----------+----------+------------+
|  123-1| X5624|    123|       1|2019-01-05|2019-01-07|       629-3|
|  629-3| X5624|    629|       3|2019-01-07|2019-01-14|       629-3|
|  918-2| X5624|    918|       2|2019-01-14|2019-01-15|       629-3|
|  307-1| X5624|    307|       1|2019-05-08|2019-05-11|       307-1|
|  478-3| X5624|    478|       3|2019-05-11|2019-01-12|       307-1|
+-------+------+-------+--------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Using the pyspark api:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

patient_window = Window.partitionBy("pat_id").orderBy("strt_dt",F.col("dschrg_dt").desc())
patient_group_window = Window.partitionBy("pat_id","gn")

output_df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "contiguous",
        F.when(
            F.lag("dschrg_dt",1,"strt_dt").over(patient_window)==F.col("strt_dt"),0
        ).otherwise(1)
    )
    .withColumn(
        "gn",
        F.sum("contiguous").over(patient_window)
    )
    .withColumn(
        "main_rec_ind",
        F.when(
            F.datediff("dschrg_dt","strt_dt")== F.max(F.datediff("dschrg_dt","strt_dt")).over(patient_group_window), 
            F.col("GroupId")
        )
    )
    .select(
        "GroupId", 
        "pat_id", 
        "clm_num", 
        "clm_line", 
        "strt_dt", 
        "dschrg_dt",
        F.max("main_rec_ind").over(patient_group_window).alias("main_rec_ind")
    )
)
```

Using the scala api:

```scala
patientWindow = Window.partitionBy("pat_id").orderBy("strt_dt",col("dschrg_dt").desc())
patientGroupWindow = Window.partitionBy("pat_id","gn")

output_df = 
    df.withColumn(
        "contiguous",
        when(
            lag("dschrg_dt",1,"strt_dt").over(patientWindow)==col("strt_dt"),0
        ).otherwise(1)
    )
    .withColumn(
        "gn",
        sum("contiguous").over(patientWindow)
    )
    .withColumn(
        "main_rec_ind",
        when(
            datediff("dschrg_dt","strt_dt")== max(datediff("dschrg_dt","strt_dt")).over(patientGroupWindow), 
            col("GroupId")
        )
    )
    .select(
        "GroupId", 
        "pat_id", 
        "clm_num", 
        "clm_line", 
        "strt_dt", 
        "dschrg_dt",
        max("main_rec_ind").over(patientGroupWindow).alias("main_rec_ind")
    )
```

Let me know if this works for you.